# How can I assign a scope to a DOM element from the link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement a directive that that functions in a similar but not identical manner to `ng-repeat`.  The details are not important, but at the end of the process I am attempting to pass a child scope to newly created DOM elements.

```
// Clone template element
var newItem = template.clone();
// Create new scope for element
var childScope = scope.$new();
// Pass relevant file into scope
childScope[indexStr] = member;

// Push new scope into element.  <----- How to do this bit?

// Push element onto parent
template.parent().append(newItem);
// Clean up a bit
```

Naivly I tried:

```
newItem.scope = childScope;
```

but that doesn't work.  (It just overrides the `newItem.scope` function to the best of my knowledge)

I also tried

```
newItem.scope() = childScope;
```

but apparently that is an illegal construct in JS.

The documentation is somewhat sparse on this, but I will gladly RTFM if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Or do `$compile(newItem)(childScope)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for angular [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) functionality. You can use `$compile` provider to assign scope to a DOM element.

In your case do:-

```
   $compile(newItem)(childScope);
```

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

Comment: Huh.  I don't know how I missed this really.  I far as I am aware the linker function used to do this but was depreceated.  Is $compile the 'replacement' for it?

Comment: oh no it is still there, this is something you can use to compile an element to DOM and link it to a specified scope.

Comment: Sorry my bad I meant the transclude function.  The third argument to the compile function of a directive.

Comment: @maxf130 Yeah that is transclude, since that option is turned on in the directive config.. ultimately i believe underneath it is the `$compileprovider` logic that runs...

Comment: @PLS That worked nicely.  I have a whole other set of issues, but that worked.  Thanks for your help.